# Использование модуля sys в pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt5

Какое предназначение имеет модуль `sys` в использование с `PyQt` ведь по сути он может работать и без него т.е.

Пример использования с `sys`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ex(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Тест')
        self.resize(400, 400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Ex()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пример использование без `sys`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Ex(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Тест')
        self.resize(400, 400)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    main = Ex()
    main.show()
    app.exec()
```

Какой смысл использования данного модуля?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это нужно только для того, чтобы скрипт мог вернуть код возврата вызывающему процессу.

Comment: А как лучше использовать без `sys` или с просто не совсем понятно, и как понять код возврата вызывающему процессу

Comment: Каждую программу что-то запускает - другая программа или оболочка операционной системы. После завершения программа должна вернуть вызывающему процессу [число обозначающее статус завершения программы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status). Например, 0 может обозначать успешное завершение программы, а другие числа код ошибки. Поэтому правильнее использовать `sys.exit(app.exec_())`.